# Executing two commands in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a VBScript to execute a two commands. The script is as follows:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set X = objShell.Exec("opcdeploy -cmd ""dbspicao -m 0703 -r 1"" -node fssflx24.fss.india")
Set Y = objShell.Exec("opcmsg a=a o=o msg_text=X severity=Normal node=fssflx24.fss.india")
strIpConfig = objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll
WScript.Echo strIpConfig
```

What I want is when the first command "X" gets executed, it's output shall used as the `msg_text` in the second "Y" command.
But it is not happening as when the second command gets executed it captures not the output but only word "Y".

What I'm missing.
Kindly assist.

BR,
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple of problems.
First X is set to the Execobject not the output of the exec.
Second in the Y Exec you have just a string. To use a variable in a string you have to end the string after msg_text= with a " and then append the variable X and append finally the rest of the string. So the code would look like:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set execo = objShell.Exec("opcdeploy -cmd ""dbspicao -m 0703 -r 1"" -node fssflx24.fss.india")
X = execo.StdOut.ReadAll
Set Y = objShell.Exec("opcmsg a=a o=o msg_text=" & X &" severity=Normal node=fssflx24.fss.india")
```

Finally I cannot tell from your code what `objScriptExec` is supposed to be. It seems to be defined somewhere else so I don't know for sure how it is related...

Comment: I guess in the modified script Set "Y = objShell.Exec("opcmsg a=a o=o msg_text=" & X &" severity=Normal node=fssflx24.fss.india")" this part is not getting executed.

Comment: It should be executed but invisible. If you need the result you have to get it with wscript.echo Y.StdOut.ReadAll for example

Comment: Yes I tested that as well, opcmsg this generates an alert and it appears in our application console.

Comment: did you check whether X really contains only the information that you want to be passed on to the next exec? Maybe add an echo for x and check if this is really 100% what you want to pass to the next exec and not more

Comment: When I'm trying to echo the X value using following it gives me output as X only.                                                                                         Option Explicit
Dim objShell
Dim execo 
Dim X
Dim Y
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set execo = objShell.Exec("opcdeploy -cmd ""dbspicao -m 709 -r 1"" -node fssflx24.fss.india")
X = execo.StdOut.ReadAll
wscript.echo "X"

Answer (score 0):

My first command 
opcdeploy -cmd ""dbspicao -m 0703 -r 1"" -node fssflx24.fss.india 
it gives following alert.
Report For Database mpaydb1

```
                  Wed Mar 11 13:57:28 IST 2015

                Metric UDM 0709 (Report 1)
```

RESOURCE_NAME         CURRENT_UTILIZATION MAX_UTILIZATION LIMIT_VALU

---

processes           118        359   500
sessions           124        366   784
transactions      0   6  UNLIMITED

Second Command shall pick this output and generate alert using second command.
opcmsg a=a o=o msg_text=" & X &" severity=Normal node=fssflx24.fss.india

That is how it should work.

BR,
Ramesh